# java- How to add 7 days to a default date?

Tags: java

I have a current date in Java like below:

```
String currentDate = CoreUtil.parseDate(new Date());
```

This returns the date for today in the form `2019-03-26`.

I declared another date so that it should automatically add 7 days to the current date like below:

```
String defaultendDate=CoreUtil.parseDate(new Date()); + 7 days //example
```

So the defaultEnddate should be `2019-04-03`

How would I accomplish this as I don't want to use any simple date formatter?

Also, I would like to store the date as it is in `String` for reasons and secondly, I only want date, not the time. I am not using Java 8 as well, so I can't really use `LocalDate` library here.

Comment: You simply can store the final date in whatever representation you want.
Your "CoreUtil.parseDate" should transfer the "+7 date" to a String anyways, doesn't it?

Comment: I don't think that's how it works

Comment: you can use joda time lib https://www.joda.org/joda-time/. it contains many useful methods.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

LocalDate is perfect for this job:

```
LocalDate.now().plusDays(7);
```

You can get your string representation with

```
.format(DateTimeFormatter.ISO_DATE);
```

---

If you're not able to use Java 8, then you have a few options:

- Use the ThreeTen-Backport, which backports most functionality of the Java 8 JSR-310 API, normally available in the `java.time` package. [See here for details](https://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/). This package is available in Maven Central.
- You can also use [Joda Time](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/). The peculiar thing is that these two projects have almost the same layout of their websites.
- If you're otherwise not able to use ThreeTen-Backport or Joda Time, you can use this:

  > ```
  > Calendar c = Gregorian​Calendar.getInstance();
  > c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
  >
  > String s = new Simple​Date​Format("yyyy-MM-dd")
  >     .format(c.getTime());
  > ```
  >
  > **Warning**
  >   Many things are wrong with the old Date and Time API, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1969442/whats-wrong-with-java-date-time-api). Use this only if you have no other option.

Comment: Bingo, this is the modern solution.

Comment: Does this take the form of `YYYY-MM-DD`?

Comment: Although, I can't seem to find `LocalDate` on my library function. Can't import it. I believe `LocalDate` is for Java 8? Sadly, I am not using java 8

Comment: @Daredevil See the edit I made, directing you to the back-port.

Comment: Just a question, is `(Calendar.Day_OF_Month,7)` works as well?

Answer (score 1):

Use `Calendar`.

```
 Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
 cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
 Date defaultEndDate = cal.getTime();
```

Comment: Can I use `String defaultEndDate`?

Comment: You have to do `.toString()` on it.

Comment: These terrible classes were supplanted years ago by the modern *java.time* classes years ago with the adoption of JSR 310. Suggesting their use in 2019 is poor advice.

Comment: why do you use `getTime`? I only want the date.

Comment: Look at `SimpleDateFormat` to convert it to whatever string you want.

Comment: So how does it look like in the end? I don't follow

Answer (score 1):

Something like

```
LocalDate.now().plusWeeks(1);
```

would also do the cause.

Please, bare in mind using Java 8 Date/Time API for any operations with dates and times. as it addresses shortcomings of old Date and Calendar regarding thread safety, code design, time-zone logic and other.

**UPDATE:**

If you must use old Date/Time API, following code would suffice:

```
Date date = new Date();
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();  
calendar.setTime(date);  
calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 7);
System.out.println("Adding seven days: " + calendar.getTime());
date = calendar.getTime();
//your code
String currentDate = CoreUtil.parseDate(new Date());
```

Comment: I can't use LocalDate because it's on Java 8

Comment: OK, check the code for old date/time api. @Daredevil

Answer (score 0):

```
*
String dt = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd").format(new Date());  // Start date
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);  // number of days to add
        dt = sdf.format(c.getTime());  // dt is now the new date
        System.out.println(dt);

*
Use java.util.Date try this one
```

Comment: How does this return `YYYY-mm-DD`?

Comment: SimpleDateFormat is used to format and parse dates in Java.
You can create an instance of SimpleDateFormat with a date-time pattern like yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss, and then use that instance to format and parse dates to/from string